# DynamoDB 1MB limit on full item or only requested attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Suppose I make a `Query` in which I use `KeyConditionExpression` and I only want to return a subset of all attributes with `ProjectionExpression`. Does the full item size count toward the 1MB limit, or only what I'm fetching?

There is a slight ambiguity which I would like to clarify with respect to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568074/does-it-make-sense-to-limit-attributes-when-query-scan-dynamodb), because there it mentions read capacity, but not size limit.

Comment: Filters and ProjectionExpressions are always applied after the read. You can get returned "up to" 1MB in each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good question. I've decided to test it.

It seems it **doesn't change the page size**, but it **does help with performance**. My objects have a dummy data field that is quite large, so it's normal to get much better response times, given the decrease in bytes that need to be transferred.

Here is my code

```java
// Without Projection
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
double avgPageSize = 0;

for (var page : table.scan()) {
  avgPageSize = (avgPageSize + page.items().size()) / 2;
}

System.out.println("Without Projection ms " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
System.out.println("Average Page size " + avgPageSize);


// With projection
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
avgPageSize = 0;
scanEnhancedRequest = ScanEnhancedRequest.builder()
  .addAttributeToProject("PK")
  .build();

for (var page : table.scan(scanEnhancedRequest)) {
  avgPageSize = (avgPageSize + page.items().size()) / 2;
}

System.out.println("With Projection ms " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
System.out.println("Average Page size " + avgPageSize);
```

And the results

```
Without Projection ms 13862
Average Page size 3062.7655089609325

With Projection ms 2241
Average Page size 3062.7655089609325
```

So it seems the sequence is *query* -> *calculate capacity units* -> *filters* -> *pagination + projection*

The last one is just an assumption

Comment: I can confirm I also decided to test it, and I'm getting the same result, that is the 1MB is per item (including not projected attributes). Didin't check the performance so thanks for that extra info!

Comment: Performance benefits here would be minimal, it just reduces the amount of bytes sent across the wire. But it could help the efficiency of your application, reducing memory and CPU if you read a lot of large pages.

Comment: Yes, my test data is a bit unrealistic